# Word for the action of talking loudly with the people from your past in your imagination

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Someone talks loudly with the people from her past while "imagining" them to be present in the current situation when they actually aren't.
>   **This person does it consciously and gets instant gratification from it.**

What is this action called?

Comment: Intensely annoying? Profoundly disturbing? Deplorably infantile?

Comment: This person probably is  still working  through grief, bereavement.

Comment: @Josh61 +1 bereavement - that's a big word. Learned something today

Comment: Or schizophrenia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say she was play-acting.

Or playing [make-believe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/make-believe).

> 1. (disapproving) imagining or pretending things to be different or more
>      exciting than they really are
>
> *They live in a world of make-believe.*
>
> 2. imagining that something is real, or that you are somebody else, for
>      example in a child’s game
>
> *‘Let's play make-believe,’ said Sam.*

Comment: From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophrenia `Schizophrenia ... is a mental disorder often characterized by abnormal social behavior and failure to recognize what is real.` In my case, I said that the person does it consciously. She knows what she is doing and does it because she gets instant gratification from it.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius: Got it. Edited. Take a look.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Can I say - > She make-believes all the time, and she is make-believing right now? Are they correct?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius: I think so. But a native speaker is more likely to say for sure.

Answer (score 5):

*[Confabulation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confabulate)* feels too good to ignore:

> verb
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>   1 formal Engage in conversation; talk:
>   *she could be heard
>   on the telephone confabulating with someone*
>
> 2 Psychiatry Fabricate imaginary experiences as compensation for loss
>   of memory:
>   *she has lapses in attention and concentration—she may be confabulating a little*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>